# Excel VLOOKUP with variable as sheet reference

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vlookup

I currently have this kind of Function :

```
=VLOOKUP(A6&Values!$A$6,'pathToMyFile]Sheet1'!$A:$I,5,FALSE)
```

And i'd like to create a kind of variable in another sheet(as for 'Values!$A$6') but for my path to file like : 
`=VLOOKUP(A6&Values!$A$6,'Values!$A$8'!$A:$I,5,FALSE)`

The aim is that for futher KPI calculation the only parameter to change is the name of the document in a single cell.

any advice or tips or even solution?

Comment: You can use 'indirect' function. see a good tutorial here - http://www.contextures.com/xlFunctions05.html

Comment: How should i use it ? What i understand in this tutorial it's that you can calculate using some kind of ID of something like that, my issue is that i don't succed to put a string as variable .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have 3 sheets:

- One overview sheet (named: **Overview**)
- Two sheets where you have the discount percentages of different products (Product A, Product B, ...) split by month (named: **March** and **April**)

So for example, sheet=March includes:

- A1: Product / B1: Discount
- A2: Product A / B2: 10%
- A3: Product B / B3: 12%
- ...

We can reference in the sheet 'Overview' to the other sheets (i.e. March and April) using the following VLOOKUP formula:

```
=VLOOKUP(A5,INDIRECT($B$2&"!A:B"),2,FALSE)
```

... where **A5** is the product (Product A, Product B, ...) you are looking for, **$B$2** is the dynamic reference cell where you can (e.g. using a dropdown-list) select a month (March, April) and **2** indicates the second column (i.e. the 'Discount' column) and **FALSE** to 'Exact match'.

**Note** : The function INDIRECT() only works (1) within the workbook or (2) with workbooks that are open during the calculation time. If the external workbook is closed, it will result in a #REF! error.

Hope this helps!

Comment: My issue is that i have to "send" to my formula a path wich is a string, and it seems that i can't using this

Comment: The function INDIRECT() only works (1) within the workbook or (2) with workbooks that are open during the calculation time. If the external workbook is closed, it will result in a **#REF! error**. See [this](https://superuser.com/questions/535871/indirect-gives-a-ref-error-for-reference-to-external-workbook-where-making-a-d) question.

Comment: Can you please help me with the synthaxei'm quite new on Excel advance function

Comment: I made this : =VLOOKUP(A6&Values!$A$6,INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("[",DocumentName,".xlsx]Sheet1'!$A:$I")),5,FALSE)